# What is the delay on SharePoint 2010s SocialDataService?

Tags: ajax, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

If I use any of the CRUD methods of SocialDataService (eg: AddComment), I find that even once the POST has returned successfully SharePoint has not actually processed the change. By that I mean that a quick call to GetCommentsOnUrl will return the old data, even though I am clearly making my request only after receiving a reply.

**Is there a specific delay time I can wait to be sure SP has had time to process the change?** If I'm using AJAX to perform changes to a page (which could in the meantime have also been changed by other users) I'd like to present the most up-to-date version, so how long do I wait before re-polling the web service?

edit: longer than 1 second, less than 1.5 is this a server setting or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another pointless SP question, answer then is 1.5s. Feel free to post an answer if you know anything about this issue and I'll swap the check-mark.

Answer (score 0):

The social data service uses this user profile synchronization service in the background:

User Profile Service Application – Social Rating Synchronization Job

The service is set to run every hour OOTB.

Comment: How could that be true? That would mean comments wouldn't exist for an hour after posting them.

Comment: See: http://www.ride-the-bytes.com/?p=1064 and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870(v=office.14).aspx

I don't know if it applies to comments but I know that for ratings and tages it is 1 hour.

Comment: Yup, that's why their rating system is useless. Comments are slightly less horrible, but who knows, maybe they're also run on a timer job that nobody talks about. I try not to dig too deep into SharePoint problems, it just leads to sadness.